# Как настроить стиль кода scss (кодгайд) в редакторе sublime text 3 или в других редакторах?

Tags: html, css, gulp

Не подскажите как вы редактируете sass(scss) или less файлы на предмет стиля кода? Есть плагин на многие редакторы CssComb, где есть конфигурационный файл с настройками .csscomb.json. Все как бы нормально, но вот он не делает отступы (пустые строки) между селекторами. Сейчас у меня вот так:

```
.page-footer {
     background: #2e4054;
     .social-icons {
         display: inline-block;
         margin-top: 22px;
         padding-right: 43px;
         padding-left: 0;

         text-align: center;
         .social-icons--link {
             display: inline-block;
             padding-right: 0;
             padding-left: 14px;

             text-align: center;
         }
     }
 }
```

а хочу чтобы было так:

```
.page-footer {
     background: #2e4054;

     .social-icons {
         display: inline-block;
         margin-top: 22px;
         padding-right: 43px;
         padding-left: 0;
         text-align: center;

         .social-icons--link {
             display: inline-block;
             padding-right: 0;
             padding-left: 14px;
             text-align: center;
         }
     }
 }
```

Но как я понял пустая строка между селекторами не настраивается. Так же есть плагин для галпа, но опять же, он стилизует после компилирования.

Может кто подскажет, как можно отредактировать по кодгайду SASS(SCSS) или LESS  файлы до сборки их в css на продакшен? Может есть какие то еще инструменты о которых я не знаю. Спасибо!